# Unable to get JSON response selected city id from dropdown in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, drop-down-menu

JSON response like this

```
{
"result": {
    "cities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "city": "North and Middle Andaman",
            "state_id": 32
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "city": "South Andaman",
            "state_id": 32
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "city": "Nicobar",
            "state_id": 32
        },
        {
            "id": 330,
            "city": "Mumbai suburban",
            "state_id": 12
        },
```

I am showing cities in textfield with `TextFieldEditingChanged and dropdown`

**code:** with this code i can show city list in dropdown and got selected city in textfield but **i need selected city id as well**.. which i am unable to get

if i print `print(item, self?.cityId)`. here Mumbai suburban id is 330 but got dropdown index 2... how do i get selected city id from dropdown, please guide me

o/p

> Mumbai suburban Optional(2)

```
@IBAction func cityTextFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
  
    var tempArray = [String]()

    if sender.text?.count != 0 {

        for eachData in cityResultDict?.cities ?? []{

            if let wordToSearch = sender.text{
                let range = eachData.city?.lowercased().range(of: wordToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)

                if range != nil {
                    tempArray.append(eachData.city ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    showDropDown(with: tempArray, from: sender) { [weak self] (item, index) in
        self?.locationTextField.text = item
        self?.cityId = cityResultDict?.cities?[index].id ?? 0

        print(item, self?.cityId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i print print(item, self?.cityId). here Mumbai suburban id is 330 but got dropdown index 2..

Because you are making a new array which is `tempArray` matching with your search condition when you `showDropDown`.

I don't know how you implement your `showDropDown`. But this is a key for your code

Code will be like this

```swift
var tempArray = [String]()
var tempCityId = [String]() // I not recommend slipt like this which one is for name city and one is for your id

if sender.text?.count != 0 {

    for eachData in cityResultDict?.cities ?? []{

        if let wordToSearch = sender.text{
            let range = eachData.city?.lowercased().range(of: wordToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)

            if range != nil {
                tempArray.append(eachData.city ?? "")
                // make new array to store your cityId too
                tempId.append(eachData.cityId ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
}
showDropDown(with: tempArray, from: sender) { [weak self] (item, index) in
    self?.locationTextField.text = item
    self?.cityId = tempCityId[index].id ?? 0 // get the id form your tempCityId too

    print(item, self?.cityId)
}
```

**Notice:** This way I don't recommend. You can make a new struct which store all your reaching City or a struct only store your `cityName` and `cityId` which easier for you.

I build this way just for easier for you to realize and because I don't know how you build your `showDropDown`

Comment: `showDropDown(with : [String]?, from...` dropdown accepts [String]

Comment: any other way with out creating another array `tempCityId`

Comment: Dear @Swift, make your ``showDropDown`` accept a struct like ``showDropDown(with : [City]?, from...`` so you can simply take ``item.cityId``

Comment: i cant do that change.. because that dropdown is used in many other screens.. edited my post with screen shot

Comment: i need to search the city and then select

Comment: Dear @Swift, the hint is simply making a combine array with have attribute with store your city name and your city ID then you can have both attributes or more. I have divided into what is you missing pieces for you to easier understand. This is not a free writing service.